# Django model class and relationships between them

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.7

I want to create a model class "Event" ( event will be of two type one_time_event and recurring_event), and separate model class for both "one_time_event" and "recurring_event".

So in the table Event, I want to have something like this

```
event_id                   event_type(2choices)                    event_type_id
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                           one_time_event                one_time_event_Object
2                           recurring_event               recurring_event_object
3                           one_time_event                one_time_event_Object
4                           recurring_event               recurring_event_object
```

so the question is how do i define my model class to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`GenericForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) available from the `contenttypes` contributed app.

In short, you'll create one key that can point to different models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class OneTimeEvent(models.Model):
   # your normal fields here

class RecurringEvent(models.Model):
   # your normal fields here

class Event(models.Model):
   # your normal fields here
   content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)  # A link to any kind of content
   object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField() # The id for the linked object
   event_type = models.GenericForeignKey() # This can point to any kind of object
```

Now, you can do this:

```
recurring_event = RecurringEvent.objects.create()
event = Event()
event.event_type = recurring_event
event.save()
```

Comment: Yeah can I have other fields in OneTimeEvent & RecurringEvent class?

Comment: Yes, I just gave an example. These are just like any other model classes. There is nothing special about them.